# Javascript simple validation issue

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm new In Javascript, it's my learning process.

Well, I've a html form where i'm trying to validate it with Javascript. Following is my some validation code:

```
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("First name must be filled out");
return false;
}

var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

if (x==null || x=="")
{
alert("Emaill address require");
return false;
}
```

In this form I've 2 drop down field where i want to validate it if both field are empty with following code:

```
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["pf_social_plan"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");

var p=document.forms["myForm"]["pf_combo_offer_details"].value;
var atpos=p.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=p.lastIndexOf(".");


if (x==null || x=="" && p==null || p=="")
{
alert("Select only one drop down field");
return false;
}
```

But It's doesn't work property. I know there is a problem in my code. Can you guys help me plz  ?
Thank You.

**Update html code:**

```
<tr>
<td>Social Combo Packages Combo A-C= tweets / pin / likes & Youtube page 1 service 
</td>
<td valign="top">
<select id="pf_social_plan" name="pf_social_plan">
<option value="" selected="selected">--Select--</option>
<option value="Social Combo Package A = $25.00">Social Combo Package A = 
$25.00</option>
<option value="Social Combo Package B = $42.00">Social Combo Package B = 
$42.00</option> 
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td valign="top">social Combo offer details</td>
<td valign="top"><textarea id="pf_combo_offer_details" name="pf_combo_offer_details" 
rows="5" cols="75" placeholder="Please provide social Combo offer details"><?php 
if(isset($_POST['pf_combo_offer_details'])) echo $_POST['pf_combo_offer_details']; 
?></textarea>   </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Zenith, I updated my HTML Code.

Comment: You need to give us the **whole** HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a dropdown do this:

```
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["pf_social_plan"];
var value = x.options[x.selectedIndex].value;
```

Answer (score 0):

To validate the select (dropdown) do this:

```
 var xSelectedValue=document.forms["myForm"]["pf_social_plan"].value;

 var pSelectedValue=document.forms["myForm"]["pf_combo_offer_details"].value;



 if ((xSelectValue != null || xSelectValue != '') && (pSelectValue != null || pSelectValue != ''))
 {
       alert("Select only one drop down field");
       return false;
 }

 return true;
```